# pixlr api return temp image path is not working

Tags: php, pixlr

Below is my code.

```
<a href="http://apps.pixlr.com/editor/?method=GET&amp;locktarget=true&amp;locktitle=true&amp;title=1550743577_resize&amp;image=http%3A%2F%2F46.105.78.243%2Ffiles%2Ftemp_location_images%2F962396628%2F1550743577_resize.jpg&amp;target=http%3A%2F%2F46.105.78.243%2Fen%2Fsave-image&amp;exit=http%3A%2F%2F46.105.78.243%2Fen%2Fadd-single-location"></a>
```

When i have clicked on this link and modify the image and save so pixlr web api return on defined specific path with one object output.

Output return by pixlr api.

```
    Array
(
    [image] => http://apps.pixlr.com/_temp/5c6e7870455714fa4000027b.jpg
    [type] => jpg
    [title] => 1550743576_resize2
    [state] => replace
)
```

But this image link of array is not working that means when i try to get image from this link it will be show like below image.

[image]

So please help me to find where i am wrong in my code.

Thanks In Advance.

Comment: Better ask pixlr what is wrong

Comment: There are not any facility of contact support at pixlr website.

Comment: @executable Do you help to check code where i am wrong? Do you check at your side once if you have already used this before. So it will be more helpful for me.

Answer (score 0):

Answer from Pixlr support On Fri, Feb 22, 2019:

> Our technical team is in the process of enhancing the API platform to
>   non-flash based. The new API platform will be developed based on PixlrX.
>
> At the moment, our API platform will be temporarily unavailable.
>
> Sorry for any inconvenience caused. Do reach out if you need any
>   assistance.

Comment: Thanks for your answer of this update. But How can i trust on your sentence? Can you give me any link of the Pixlr webs page that shows this sentences so i will check it.

Comment: That was their answer to my email.

Comment: Okay then please, can you give me one screenshot of that email? This will be great for me.